# How to set height = width with angularjs directives to get a square div according to bootstrap grid system?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, angularjs-directive, responsive

I've been playing a little bit with angularjs to create my own app and the following idea came to my mind:

I want to make a directive to make responsive square divs that work with bootstrap grid system.

*Before going any further, I've already searched thoroughly for the past 4 hours and, tho I've found interesting approaches, none of them gave me a solution.*

So i came up with the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('ClientsApp', []);

app.directive('wh', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var x = element.css[width];
        element.css({
            'width': x,
            'height': x,
            'border-radius':'1rem',
        });
    };
});
```

But, I can't make it work (I've been using angular for 2 days now). Intead if i do this:

```
var app = angular.module('ClientsApp', []);

app.directive('wh', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var x = element.css[width];
        element.css({
            'width': **x + 'em'**,
            'height': **x + 'em'**,
            'border-radius':'1rem',
        });
    };
});
```

It works when the x in attribute wh='x' is set.

What I want is to make 'x' (in the angularjs script) equal to the width value given by the col-vw-x bootstrap class, so when I write:

```
<div href="#" class="col-sm-**x**" wh></div>
```

I automatically get a square div, acording to the bootstrap class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working plunker based on your code.](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9xQkkZgPNNcWlAAGToC)

In my HTML I have:

```
  <div href="#" class="col-sm-4" wh style='background-color: blue;'></div>
```

My directive looks like:

```
app.directive('wh', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
      var width = attrs.class.substring(1+attrs.class.lastIndexOf('-'));
      console.log('Directive width: '+width);

        var x = element.css[width];
        element.css({
            'width': width + 'em',
            'height': width + 'em',
            'border-radius':'1rem',
        });
    };
});
```

Basically I read the class attributes and get col-sm-4 in my example. Look for the last '-' and get the rest of the string (i.e. 4 in my example.) Then I used your code and it works.

You may want to add some error checking in the directive as I am using indexOf and substring, but the general idea is there.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked very well for me. I never thought about using "substring" and "lasIndexOf" (it took me some time to understand what was happening jajaja).

Still i made one little change so it would adjust to bootstap's grid system setting:

            'width': width*100/12 + 'vw',
            'height': width*100/12 + 'vw',

Comment: Glad it helped. The indexof and substring are an old trick... It tends to give exception in Java or similar languages if you can't find the indexof, etc. In JavaScript, it probably won't crash your app if you don't pass the correct format. A cleaner way is probably a regular expression/regex.